# Converting from While Loop Structure to Function Call

Tags: python

there's an example in Learn Python The Hard Way -- Python -- That I'm working on and I just couldn't quite think through it. I think I'm hiccuping on the theoretical elements of changing the program more than the writing the physical lines, but I could be completely wrong.

```
i = 0
numbers =[]
while i < 6:
    print "At the top i is %d" %i
    numbers.append(i)

    i += 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" %i

print "The numbers: "
for num in numbers:
    print num
```

This is the code that I'm working with and the question/ prompt reads as follows:

> Convert this while-loop to a function that you can call, and replace 6 in the test (i < 6) with a variable.

If you can help and secondarily write out the significance of each line in layman's terms, that'd be of great help to me.

Here is my first attempt:

```
def whilefunc(i):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        print "At the top i is %d" %i
        numbers.append(i)
        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom, i is %d" %i
    for num in numbers: 
        print num
```

Comment: What do you need, comments?

Comment: You have a few problems that leap out.   First, you have put more than just the while loop into the function.   They didn't ask you to do that, and it has made you miss the point of having the function.   Second you have defined the variable 'i' twice, and I think you don't know this.   First, you have 'i' as the parameter of the function, but you never use it inside the function.   Then you use 'i' as the loop parameter.   When you print 'i' this is the value you are printing.  Finally, you don't show us how you call the function.  What are you expecting the result from the function to be?

Comment: Not to mention you are incrementing manually the loop variable i ... don't do that!   The for loop does that for you.

Comment: @GreenAsJade when I used "i" as a parameter / argument in the function I didn't know that I couldn't access or modify that within the body of the function call. Maybe I don't fully understand the individuality of the loop parameter / iterator here.

Comment: You can modify it inside the body of the function.   But you would expect to actually _use_ the value that is passed in, first, eh?    In your case, I imagine that you pass in the number 6, but you set 'i' to  zero as soon as you start the loop, without first checking what value was passed in ...

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the excercise in the book is asking you to come up with a recursive function that replaces the while loop, with the goal of a solution that does not include a loop.   This would be a "non-sequitur" in terms of syllabus.     Rather, it is more simply trying to get you to see that you can have a parameterised function to call to do this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks you to imitate a while loop with function calls. You just need to call the function itself recursively.

```
def f(i,x,numbers):
    if (i < x):
        print "At the top i is %d" %i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" %i
        f(i,x,numbers)
    return numbers

numbers = f(0,6,[])
for num in numbers:
    print num
```

**Output:**

```
At the top i is 0
Numbers now:  [0]
At the bottom, i is 1
At the top i is 1
Numbers now:  [0, 1]
At the bottom, i is 2
At the top i is 2
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2]
At the bottom, i is 3
At the top i is 3
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3]
At the bottom, i is 4
At the top i is 4
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
At the bottom, i is 5
At the top i is 5
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
At the bottom, i is 6
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: The OP doesn't even understand a for loop.  I think recursion might be a bit of a leap :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade, I might have misunderstood the question O_O

Comment: (I'm guessing that in the book, what they mean by "function that you can call" would be more obvious from the context!?)

Comment: I do understand a for-loop. I also understand while loops. It's just been a while since I've placed them within the context of a function.
@Fabricator what does the "return" do in this section of code? I thought about using an if-statement as shown, but that "return" may have been my missing link for recursion.

Comment: @black_bird every function return some value. In this case `return` returns numbers, which is third argument in function, initialized as empty list in `numbers = f(0,6,[])` and filled with `numbers.append(i)`. Even If you omit `return` statement in a function, function still returns value `None`.

Comment: @Reloader When you say "return some value" how does it return it? By printing it to the screen, or is that return serving a bigger purpose under the hood?

Comment: It is returning to function _caller_. Here `numbers = f(0,6,[])` - let the (returned) result of function `f` be assigned to variable `numbers`

Comment: @Reloader , thank you for help with the disambiguation.

Comment: So @black_bird do you understand that the variable "numbers" inside the function in this example is not the same as the variable "numbers" outside it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade, I believe so, correct me if I'm wrong, but the "numbers" function argument / parameter is being appended in the `numbers.append(i)` , so those are the same "numbers" as well as the numbers in `f(i,x,numbers)` and `return numbers`. I also believe that the `return numbers` is referencing the argument/param in the function `f(i,x,numbers)`.

`numbers = f(0,6,[])` assigns the value of the function `f(i,x,numbers)` when the values of `numbers = []` (initiating an empty list), 0 and 6 are passed through the function.

Is this right?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Could the variable `numbers` be renamed to avoid confusion?

Comment: I think your description is right - it sounds like you understand that the `numbers` outside the function is a different variable to the `numbers` in side the function, which is important to appreciate.  I certainly would name them differently for clarity (as I did in my answer).

Answer (score 3):

The initial question above posed by black_bird is [Study Drill 1 from Exercise 33](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex33.html) from Zed Shaw's [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

In ex33 SD1, Shaw asks you to take his example while loop from the exercise and convert to a function replacing the hard-coded loop condition to a variable. While some of the answers above accomplish the goal, none follows the instructions outlined by Shaw which would require passing only one argument (the last answer above is close, but passes two). Below are two answers. The first is the best answer in accord with Shaw's Study Drill 1 from ex33 in line with what the reader has learned to that point. Only one argument is passed. The second gets user input instead of hard coding a number in the function call.

First answer:

```
def buildList(num):
    numList = []    
    i = 0       
    while i < num:
        numList.append(i)
        i += 1
        print "i: %d, " % i,
        print "list: ", numList
    #note: you don't need to return a value

#you can hard code any number here, of course
buildList(6)
```

Here is the second answer:

```
def buildList(num):
    #Convert num to int else infinite loop because num is a string
    num = int(num)  
    numList = []    
    i = 0       
    while i < num:
        numList.append(i)
        i += 1
        print "i: %d, " % i,
        print "list: ", numList

#getting/passing a string; converted to int within the function
answer = raw_input("Enter a number less than 10: ")
buildList(answer)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to this question, but I too am taking this class and thought I could add to the discussion. I think the below code correctly answers 1-3 of the study drills for this lesson.

```
    numbers = []
    def numbers_list(x,y):
        i = 0
        while i < x:
            print "At the top of i is %d" % i
            numbers.append(i)
            i += y
            print "Numbers now: ", numbers
            print "At the bottom of i is %d" % i
        return numbers

    numbers_list(6,1)
    print "the numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num
```

Output will be the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

Think Zed Shaw just wanted us to convert the while loop (not the for loop) to a function... so I think it's just as simple as this.

```
def functiontocallforlist(x):
numList = []
i = 0
while i < x:
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numList.append(i)

    i += 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numList
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

#You can put whatever number you want as x really.
functiontocallforlist(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def list_of_numbers(length):
       working_list = []
       for i in range(length):
          print "At the top i is %d" %i
          working_list.append(i)
          print "numbers now: ", working_list

       return working_list


    numbers = list_of_numbers(6)

    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
       print num
```

Output:

```
At the top i is 0
numbers now:  [0]
At the top i is 1
numbers now:  [0, 1]
At the top i is 2
numbers now:  [0, 1, 2]
At the top i is 3
numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3]
At the top i is 4
numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
At the top i is 5
numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
The numbers: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def while_loop(number, increment):

    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < number:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)   

        i += increment
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


    print "The numbers: "


    for num in numbers:
        print num

while_loop(int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")), int(raw_input("Enter increment: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the input from the user for i
i = int(input("i>"))
# create an empty list and fill it later
numbers = []
# get input from user for the variable to use in while
num = int(input("num>"))
# Create a function and use while loop
def yourfunction(i):
    while i < num:
        # if user input for "i" is less than the user input for "num"
        print(f"at the top of i is {i}")
        # once i is printed, Add i to the list
        numbers.append(i)
        #once i is added to the list, print the list
        print("numbers now", numbers)
        # Then increment i by 1
        i = i + 1
        #once incremented, print i and repeat
        print(f"At the bottom of i is {i}")
# Call the function
yourfunction(i)
# print the newly created list
print(f"the new list is {numbers}")
# use of for loop 
for num in numbers:
    print(num)][1]
```

Output is available in the below link

Answer (score 0):

As @alwayslearnedstuff answered I guess it's true that ZED SHAW didn't meant to create a function that works like a while loop instead of using while loop. But I miss understood that and after trying for a long time I made that using for loop inside. I just want to share my interesting code here although you already have gotten your answer.

```
def function_as_while(length):
numbers = []
for i in range(length):
    print(f"At the top i is {i}")
    numbers.append(i)
    print(f"numbers now: {numbers}")

return numbers
numbers = function_as_while(int(input("Enter list length:  ")))
print("The numbers: ")
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

What I did is I created a Function that works as a while loop. And for more fun I gave the `length` parameter with a value that I took as input from user by `int(input("Enter list length:  "))` this little part.

I hope you liked it!!

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution that I think might be easier!  I am just getting started and I think my ignorance has aided in keeping it simple.  Also, I am working from Zed A Shaw’s Python 3 book.

Here’s what I came up with:

```
def loop(material):  #here is where I define the function (loop) with a variable (material)

    i = 0      #the rest of the exercise can remain pretty much intact
    numbers = []

    while i < material:    #I have replaced the number 6 with my variable
        print(f”At the top i is {i}”)
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + 1
        print(“Numbers now: “, numbers)
        print(f”At the bottom i is {i}”)

    print(“The numbers: “)

    for num in numbers:
        print(num)

loop(10)   #here I call the function and define the variable as 10
```

Hopefully this makes sense!